# Limit of a simple Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, improper-integrals

Need to show that $$\lim_{t\to 1^-}(1-t)\int_0^t\frac{g(s)}{(1-s)^2}ds=g(1)$$ for any continuous function $g(s)$.

I tried a variable change $u=1/(1-s)$ which gives $du=ds/(1-s)^2$ with $$(1-t)\int_1^{\frac{1}{1-t}}g(1-\frac{1}{u})du$$

I cannot seem to figure out how to get to the limit, given that thus far it's correct.

Comment: If you know of l'Hospital's rule, you can apply it.

Comment: @mickep How do you know that the integral diverges if $g(1)=0$? If $g(1)\ne0$ then it diverges and L'Hopital does the work. Moreover, if $g\ge 0$ (or $g\le 0$) near $s=1$, then one can apply L'Hopital. But if $g$ takes is a sinusoidal type near $1$....

Comment: @TitoEliatron That is not necessary to apply the rule. It is sufficient that the denominator tends to $+\infty$ (for example). And here one could use $1/(1-t)$ as the denominator.

Comment: This is a non-standard application of L'Höpital, but Works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Theorem 5.13 in Rudin's "Principles of mathematical analysis" (slightly restated)

> If $f$ and $h$ are real and differentiable in $(0,1)$ and if $h'(x)\neq 0$ in a neighborhood of $1$, and $h(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to 1^-$, and in addition $f'(x)/h'(x)\to A$ as $x\to 1^-$, then $f(x)/h(x)\to A$ as $x\to 1^-$.

Applying this to
$$
f(x)=\int_0^x\frac{g(s)}{(1-s)^2}\,ds\quad\text{and}\quad h(x)=\frac{1}{1-x},
$$
we get (here we use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the property that $g$ is continuous)
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{h'(x)}=\frac{g(x)/(1-x)^2}{1/(1-x)^2}=g(x)\to g(1)\quad (x\to 1^-).
$$
Hence, the limit you look for (check the conditions) is also $g(1)$.

Comment: Very nice answer.